# Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""] on AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the aws-sdk for node.js and trying to upload an image with Content-Type: 'image/png'.

I am creating a presignedpost:

```
const post = s3.createPresignedPost({
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Fields: {
        key: 'hubspot_customer_portal/' + fileName
    },
    Expires: 60, // seconds
    Conditions: [
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
        { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' },
        ['content-length-range', 0, 1048576],
    ],
})

return post
```

But I get `Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]` in the response.

My CORS-policy on my bucket is

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}]
```

I use Axios to make a post-request with the presigned data

```
const filename = encodeURIComponent(file.name)
const res = await APIService.upload(filename, folder) // Get presigned data
const { url, fields } = res.data
const formData = new FormData()

Object.entries({ ...fields, file }).forEach(([key, value]: any) => {
    formData.append(key, value)
})

const upload = await axios.post(url, formData)
```

I've also tried making the post request like this

```
await axios.post(url, formData,{headers:{'Content-Type':'image/png'}})
```

Comment: What is the intention for condition  ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]?

Comment: @MilanGatyas I want it to accept content type image. Basically I want to upload files to S3 and change the Meta data to Content Type image/png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I don't need the conditions at all and instead of putting `{ 'Content-Type': 'image/png' },` in the Conditions, I put it in the Fields instead